# Let M be a $3\times 3$ real symmetric matrix with eigenvalues $0,2$ and $a$ with the respective eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $M$ be a $3\times 3$ real symmetric matrix with eigenvalues $0, 2$ and $a$ with the respective eigenvectors $u = (4,b,c)^{t} , v = (-1,2,0)^{t}$ and $w = (1,1,1)^{t}$. Consider the following statements:

I. $a+b-c = 10$

II. The vector $x = \left(0,\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)^{t}$ satisfies $Mx = v+w$.

III. For any $d\in \text{span}\{u,v,w\}$ , $Mx= d$  has a solution.

IV. The trace of the matrix $M^{2}+2M$ is $8$.

($y^{t}$ denotes the transpose of the vector y)

Which of the above statements are TRUE?

My Attempt: III is not true because M is not invertible and span(u,v,w) = $\mathbf{R}^3$. But what about other statement.

Comment: What do you know about symmetric matrices and their relationship with eigenvalues and eigenvectors? That is a question that can help you.

Comment: Symmetric Matrix will have $6$ unknown elements , with $3$ more unknowns $ a , b , c $ , hence total $ 6 + 3 = 9 $ unknowns. Eigenvector Equations will give $ 3 \times 3 = 9 $ linear Equations. Solving that will give Details to Evaluate the various Parts.

Answer (score 1):

First of all we determine $a,b$ and $c$. To this end we use that eigenvectors of $M$ to distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal.

Since $v$ and $w$ are not orthogonal, we get $a=2.$

$0$ and $2$ are eigenvalues of $M$ , hence $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal, thus $b=2$.

$0$ and $2$ are eigenvalues of $M$ , hence $u$ and $w$ are orthogonal, thus $c=-6$.

This shows that I. is not true.

II: we have $v+w= 2x$ , hence $Mx= \frac{1}{2}M(v+w)= \frac{1}{2}(2v+2w)=v+w, $ therefore II is true.

III: $0$ is an eigenvalue of $M$, hence $Im(M) \ne \mathbb R^3.$ Since $\text{span}\{u,v,w\}= \mathbb R^3,$ option III is not true.

IV: this is your turn ! Observe that the trace of $M^2+2M$ is the sum of the eigenvalues of $M^2+2M$ counted with algebraic multiplicity.